# Get list of files to be committed by particular git commit command

Tags: git

**Input**: git repo directory and commit command: like `git commit -m "commit staged"` or `git commit -a -m "comit all file"` or any other `git commit ...`

**Output**: list of files that are going to be added in the commit by this command.

Possible solution:

- get staged files by: `git diff --cached --name-status`
- check if `git commit` command contains `--all` flag
- if `--all`: get not staged files by `git diff --name-only` and take this list + staged changes list
- if no `--all`: get only staged changes list

Is this algorithm cover all the cases of git commit command and repo state?

Comment: No - you can also explicitly tell the commit command to commit only specific files: `git commit -m "Message" file1.txt file2.txt`

Comment: ok thanks any other options?

Comment: What are you using this for?

Comment: Before a commit is really done, the files to be committed are not fixed. Put this task in a `post-commit` hook and you could get an instant feedback which files have been committed.

Comment: I need this for pre-commit check)

Comment: @WHITECOLOR Oh, in that case write a [pre-commit hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks). At that point I believe what's about to be committed will be staged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the complete state of the working directory and staging area in one go with `git status --porcelain`.

```
$ git status --porcelain
A  that
MM this
?? blah
```

The first column is the status of the staging area, the second is the status of the working directory. The above says `that` has been added to the staging area, `this` has both staged and unstaged modifications, and `blah` is untracked.

Here's the same thing long-hand.

```
$ git status
On branch feature
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   that
    modified:   this

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   this

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    blah
```

---

But I suspect what you really want is to be able to review what's going to change before you commit it. In this case, I'd suggest you don't do this. Instead...

1. Don't use `-m`.
2. Use `-v`.
3. Fix any mistakes with `git commit --amend`.

`git commit -m` is a bad habit to get into. It means your commit messages will be a single line and lacking in detail. A good commit message is something like:

> Brief summary.
>
> Details, details, details.

`git commit -m` discourages that, and those details will be important down the road, ***and you can never get them back***. Its worth the extra few seconds.

More importantly, a regular `git commit` that pulls up an editor already shows you what's going to be committed.

```
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
# On branch feature
# Changes to be committed:
#       new file:   that
#       modified:   this
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#       modified:   this
#
# Untracked files:
#       blah
#
```

Even better, if you use `git commit -v`, you'll get the full diff to review. I use this so often I have it aliased as `git ci` (Check In).

```
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
# On branch feature
# Changes to be committed:
#       new file:   that
#       modified:   this
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#       modified:   this
#
# Untracked files:
#       blah
#
# ------------------------ >8 ------------------------
# Do not touch the line above.
# Everything below will be removed.
diff --git a/that b/that
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..e69de29
diff --git a/this b/this
index 73e4f83..f129e32 100644
--- a/this
+++ b/this
@@ -4,3 +4,5 @@ fix
 1
 2
 3
+4
+
```

Finally, unlike other version control systems, commits in Git aren't immediately shared. Everything is local until you `git push`. That means if you make a mistake in a commit, you can quickly fix it. Just make the fix and `git commit --amend` and the last commit will be updated.

So rather than adding a bunch of layers to prevent yourself from making a goof, just fix the goof. That's the beauty of version control!

Comment: It's worth noting here that "commits are local" is *not* in fact unique to Git. Mercurial works precisely the same way, with some added protection in modern Mercurial: each commit has a *phase* associated with it (secret, draft, or public) and commits are automatically upgraded to "public" phase when pushed. Commands like `hg amend` and `hg histedit` know that you should only edit unpublished commits. (Despite hg's obviously-better interface here, I use and prefer Git anyway :-) )

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and advice)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `git commit -v` as suggested above to review the list of files modified, be warned the line before that list will change with Git 2.14.x/2.15 (Q4 2017).

The explanation of the cut-line in the commit log editor has been
slightly tweaked.

See [commit 8c4b1a3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8c4b1a3593fca2a5315aa5a266fb11d5bdb78330) (13 Sep 2017) by [Kaartic Sivaraam (`sivaraam`)](https://github.com/sivaraam).
Helped-by: [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 77f4539](https://github.com/git/git/commit/77f45395b01ad27534f751a74233c77912d80758), 25 Sep 2017)</sup>

> ### `commit-template`: change a message to be more intuitive
>
> It's not good to use the phrase '`do not touch`' to convey the information that the cut-line should not be modified or removed as it could possibly be mis-interpreted by a person who doesn't know that the word 'touch' has the meaning of 'tamper with'.
>   Further, it could make translations a little difficult as it might not have the intended meaning in a few languages when translated as such.
>
> So, use more intuitive terms in the sentence.

So instead of

```
Do not touch the line above.
Everything below will be removed.
```

You will have:

```
Do not modify or remove the line above.
Everything below it will be ignored.
```